# Spring Social Twitter REST API and "until" date

Tags: java, spring, rest, api, twitter

I am trying to retrieve tweets for a hashtag using Spring Social Twitter APIs.

When I pass the date in required format in "until" field, I am not able to retrieve the tweets. 
I even tried directly invoking the REST API using https://dev.twitter.com/rest/tools/console (example https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?
q=<>&lang=en&count=10&until=2016-12-10).

However without the "until" date API works fine both through Spring and REST Tool.

Appreciate if anyone could help me understand this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Twitter Search API only searches against tweets in the last 7 days (as mentioned [in the documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search)). Thus, if your `until` field is before 7 days from the query submission, no results will return.

The only way to retrieve tweets posted longer than 7 days is to order a paid subscription to a Twitter service that has the ability to search against Twitter's historic data (i.e. [Gnip](http://support.gnip.com/apis/historical_api/), [Nuvi](https://www.nuvi.com/), etc.). There are currently no free options that achieve this objective.

Comment: I was looking for free options, indeed. Thank you for the clarification.